# expected end of statement in VB form

Tags: vb6

We get "expected : end of statement error" for the below code and VB highlights Begin VB.Form **Form1**

```
Begin VB.Form Form1
   Caption = "Form1"
   ClientHeight = 3090
   ClientLeft = 60
   ClientTop = 450
   ClientWidth = 4680
   Icon  = "Form1.frx":0000
   LinkTopic = "Form1"
   ScaleHeight = 3090
   ScaleWidth = 4680
   StartUpPosition = 3    'Windows Default
End

Attribute VB_Name = "Form1"
Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False
Attribute VB_Creatable = False
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = True
Attribute VB_Exposed = False
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That code is from a .frm file and is not editable in the IDE.

You don't need to type this information in, it is auto generated when you add edit and remove control and properties from your form.

Unlike VB.NET you cannot edit the 'designer' code in the VB6 IDE yourself.

Comment: hello Matt, thanks for your comments. I've another trouble in the module. While compiling, I get an error "user-defined type not defined", in the below line.
Private Declare Function RegQueryInfoKey Lib "advapi32.dll" Alias "RegQueryInfoKeyA" (ByVal hKey As Long, ByVal lpClass As String, lpcbClass As Long, ByVal lpReserved As Long, lpcSubKeys As Long, lpcbMaxSubKeyLen As Long, lpcbMaxClassLen As Long, lpcValues As Long, lpcbMaxValueNameLen As Long, lpcbMaxValueLen As Long, lpcbSecurityDescriptor As Long, lpftLastWriteTime As FILETIME) As Long

Comment: @RengasamiRamanujam - Please post this as a new question. It will be a lot easier to see that code then.

Comment: It may be TYPE FILETIME. Did you add this UDT declaration to your code?